# Why jQuery.inArray doesn't work on array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have array of objects

```
var arr = [
        {"id" : "1", "description" : "one"},
        {"id" : "2", "description" : "two"},
        {"id" : "3", "description" : "three"}]
```

I need get index, for example, for object with id="2".I do

```
var index = jQuery.inArray( {"id" : "2", "description" : "two"}, arr )
```

In index I get -1.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cosset777/7kg9P/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `inArray` uses `===` to compare elements, and different objects are never `===` to one another. (They're also not `==` to one another.)

E.g.:

```
var a = {"foo": "bar"};
var b = {"foo": "bar"};
console.log(a === b); // "false"
```

You'll need to create a method on them to compare them for equivalence, and then do the search yourself.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a function that takes a callback:

```
function arrayFind(arr, fn) {
    for( var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; ++i ) {
        if( fn(arr[i]) ) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

var arr = [
        {"id" : "1", "description" : "one"},
        {"id" : "2", "description" : "two"},
        {"id" : "3", "description" : "three"}
];

var result = arrayFind(arr, function(v){
    return v.id === "2" && v.description === "two";
});
console.log(result) //1
```

Answer (score 1):

As TJ said, `inArray` uses `===` (`indexOf` actually, but that's the same thing), therefore even identical literals are compared non equal. Here's a workaround:

```
var index = jQuery.inArray( 
    JSON.stringify({"id" : "2", "description" : "two"}), 
    $.map(arr, JSON.stringify) )
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7kg9P/1/

Comment: Not a good idea, the order of the properties is not significant in objects, but `JSON.stringify` may well output properties in different orders for different but equivalent objects: http://jsbin.com/ELAToPO/1 (Also: `inArray` only uses `indexOf` if the browser has it. Part of the point of `inArray` is that IE was missing `Array#indexOf` for a long time...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: note that I carefully used words "identical literals", not "equivalent objects", so you're fighting the wrong point here. As to IE7/8, jQuery, as of 2.0, doesn't support these anymore.

Comment: All due respect, but it makes no sense whatsoever to solve this problem only for identical literals and not equivalent objects. No production code should ever be delivered with such a dependency, and I'm sure you know that. As for jQuery 2.0, most people still can't use it except for intranet stuff, what with IE8 being 21% of the global browser market share. And that's going to be a *long* tail, thanks to IE9 not being available for XP.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I think you're being too pedantic here. My snippet demonstrates a quick and easy workaround for the problem and works just fine for the OP's data. Designing a universal complete deep comparator for JS objects is out of the scope of the question.

Comment: I completely disagree. This doesn't solve the OP's problem, not in a way that would work reliably in the real world. My concern is pragmatic, not pedantic. (I **am** a pedant, but I'm not being pedantic *here*. :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: "production", "pragmatic", "real world" (didn't you forget "enterprise ready"?) are just empty buzzwords that don't mean a thing here. There are many possible definitions of "object equivalence", which exactly is to be used here strongly depends on the specific project requirements, which we don't have a slightest clue about.

Comment: "Pragmatic" absolutely applies here and is not a buzzword. What you've shown **will fail** in normal situations. It may seem to work briefly in a *very* limited situation, but it's just laying a trap to fall into later. It's bad programming. End. Of. I'm shocked you're defending it. Have a final word if you like, this is not worth discussing further.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: "normal situation" is just as meaningless as "pragmatic" and "real world". Every project is unique, and the very definition of "normal" depends on the context. In this particular case, there are several possible interpretations of the question, you have arbitrarily chosen one of them and defend it passionately as if it were the only possible. I usually don't resort to personal remarks in a technical discussion, but if I were you, I'd say I'm slightly disappointed by such close-mindedness!

Comment: Yeah, right. I'm focussing on the fact that this doesn't work, not in any real way, and is not useful. Actively harmful and misleading, if anything. BTW, if you say someone is using "empty buzzwords", if you say they're being "pedantic," those are personal remarks. You can't then reasonably complain if they say they're surprised someone like yourself who normally posts useful information is sticking by something that is not useful.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: note that I was commenting your point only and not your attitude or (implied) intentions. Feel the difference. ^D

Comment: *(Comment removed)* I said I was done, so I'll be done. Best,