# Jquery - checking if value exist in a column of an associative array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to check if the an id already exist in my array. if It exists the older value should be removed, and the new value should be added to the array, if not it should be added to the array.

Here's the code that I tried but didn't work.

```
sample_array[0] = {'id' : 1, 'letter': 'a'};
sample_array[1] = {'id' : 2, 'letter': 'b'};
sample_array[2] = {'id' : 3, 'letter': 'c'};
sample_array[3] = {'id' : 4, 'letter': 'd'};
sample_array[4] = {'id' : 5, 'letter': 'e'};

input_id = 3;
count_length = sample_array.length;
input_letter = 'L'; 
idx = $.inArray(input_id, sample_array.id); // <- i think this is where it goes wrong.

if(idx ==  -1)
{
   //add to the array
   sample_array[count_length] = {'id' : input_id, 'letter': input_letter};              
}
else
{
   //remove then add to the array
   sample_array.splice(idx, 1);
   sample_array[count_length] = {'id' : input_id, 'letter': input_letter}; 
}
```

Comment: follow this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809116/how-to-use-php-in-array-with-associative-array
I hope it will help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why jQuery.inArray doesn't work on array of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111707/why-jquery-inarray-doesnt-work-on-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for a primitive value not an object, so

replace from this line onwards

```
idx = $.inArray(input_id, sample_array.id);
```

with

```
sample_array.forEach(function(value,index){
   if(value.id==input_id)
   {
     sample_array.splice(index,1);
   }
}).length;
sample_array.push({'id' : input_id, 'letter': input_letter});
```

Comment: I removed the .length because I get an error of an undefined array length. It works fine, bro thanks. I really hate arrays in javascript. haha