# Jquery - Check if objects in array exist

Tags: jquery

I am adding objects to an array like so:

```
fontSizeArray.push({element: $(y).prop("tagName").toLowerCase(), orginalSize:$(y).css("font-size"), size:$(y).css("font-size")});
```

this code inside a loop, what I am trying to do is eliminate the duplicates because some items will have the same tagName and the same font-size

I am trying to use in array, but its not working, the duplicates still remain.

```
if($.inArray({element: $(y).prop("tagName").toLowerCase(), orginalSize:$(y).css("font-size"), size:$(y).css("font-size")}, fontSizeArray) == -1)
                {
                        fontSizeArray.push({element: $(y).prop("tagName").toLowerCase(), orginalSize:$(y).css("font-size"), size:$(y).css("font-size")});
                }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867599/jquery-inarray-how-to-use-it-right

Comment: I dont know how this article helps.

Comment: Sorry should have been this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111707/why-jquery-inarray-doesnt-work-on-array-of-objects

Comment: @user979331 did you find useful my answer? if yes please don't forget to mark as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find Object in an Array you can use .grep

```
searchArray = $.grep(fontSizeArray, function(n) {
    return n.element == $(y).prop("tagName").toLowerCase() && n.orginalSize == $(y).css("font-size") && n.size == $(y).css("font-size");
});

if(searchArray.length == 0){
    console.log("Not find");
}else{
    console.log("find");
}
```

`.grep` Finds the elements of an array which satisfy a filter function. The original array is not affected, and return an array.

I use all attributes to find the object, but you can use only `tagName` to find the element to avoid push duplicates.

You can see it here https://jsfiddle.net/egfg3dmc/3/